# X3D, Shape Creation, Curve, Manipulation

Tags: x3d

I have created a box in X3D but i want to curve the top right and left corners of the box.

Any ideas on how? At the moment i have the code for the box only.

I cannot find much on the net about simple shape manipulation.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the code so that people can see what you're doing?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it manually, directly in X3D.
You have to use a software like Blender or 3DS Max to create non-primitive shapes (more complex shapes than cubes, spheres, cylinders and so on.) There you have all kinds of functions that would change your object and then you can export it in several formats, including X3D.